# Eclipse startup locale

Tags: eclipse

when I launch a product in eclipse with Java7, I see the following message:

```
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
```

when I start the product in eclipse with Java6, the locale changes

```
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_CH
```

Do you know who sets the locale or how I can influence it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the locale as runtime parameter

```
eclipse.exe -nl de
```

or in eclipse.ini:

```
-nl
de
```